# Connect to PostgreSQL from ArcMap 10.2 failed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, postgresql, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase

I have a database server PostgreSQL and Postgis. I want to connect to database from ArcMap 10.2 , I tried **Add Database Connection** from arcmap menü.

I typed my connection informations and clicked database selection box, an error occured as following. My connection info is true. I can connect from pgAdmin to database.

[image]

I did not install ArcSDE to database server. I read before that I do not need SDE after 10.0 version.

Comment: Missing PostgreSQL ODBC/JDBC driver?

Comment: is the username really "postgress"? or is it "postgres"?

Comment: @vinayan I changed username now, but not working.

Comment: @CraigRinger I have installed ODBS driver from http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/  it is about 1.6MB but did not worked

Comment: Take a look at the question I just referenced.  I think your issue may be that while you've installed the ODBC drivers, you have not installed the client driver files into the `bin` directory of your ArcGIS software.